# Prevent form from submiting PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I don't know much about PHP, and made a simple form which sends the data to a txt file. My problem is that I can't figure out how to stop the form from submiting if some fields are'nt filled in. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

I also have a simple javascript that makes the unfilled `textareas` red and alerts the user to fill in the form correctly, but I do not want to allow the submission because it still sends the values as empty to the txt-file.

```
<?php                       
    if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $myFile = 'demo.txt';
        $titel = $_POST['filmnamn'] . ";" ;
        $betyg = $_POST['betyg'] . ";" ;
        $link = $_POST['link'] . ";" ;
        $photo = $_POST['photo'] . ";" ;
        $desc = $_POST['description'] . ";" ;
        $data = "$titel$betyg$link$photo$desc";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
        fwrite($fh, $data);

        fclose($fh);                        
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use return false to stop submition

Comment: use `javascript` validation

Comment: you should attach an eventhandler to the onsubmit event of your form and make a `event.prefentDefault()` if the input is empty...

Comment: You need both javascript and php for that. You prevent the form from submitting if some of the required fields are empty using javascript and you double-check in php again to see if the required fields are really filled in. So you should post your javascript as well.

Comment: DO NOT USE JAVASCRIPT FOR FORM VALIDATION. JS can be manipulated with firebug and by disabling JS altogether

Comment: I want to make the prevent submit in the php because i want to learn how to do it that way...

Comment: You cannot prevent a form submit in php as php is a server-side language. You can only check the sent in values and decide not to save anything if it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: You can't stop a form submission with PHP.  By the time PHP gets to see the form it's already been submitted.  You might want to look into the distinction between server side and client side scripting.  Also, if the JS is the only validation you have then your validation is worthless.  I can bypass it with almost zero effort.

Comment: cant seem to find a solution where the php does nothing, dont want anything else to happen except that submit should stop..

Comment: @spovell Have you actually read any of the comments?

Comment: i know the diffence between serverside and client side, let me refrase the question then, javascript doesnt really validate it only checks if the fields are filled in and warn you to fill in them correctly, and what i want is the php to not send anything to the txt-file if all the fields isnt filled in...

Comment: @RayHughes I wouldn't say to not use it. It can be used as a convenience, but it should always be backed up with server side validation. clicking submit and getting an alert without reloading the page is great.

Comment: @spovell - I wasnt implying not to use JS for validation, perhaps I miss worded what I was saying. It shouldnt be used as the only validation method as it was implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called server-side validation.
What you should do is test your variables before anything. This will write i the file only if filemnamn and betyg variables aren't empty :

```
          <?php                     
                if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
                    if( $_POST['filmnamn'] != "" &&    $_POST['betyg'] != "") {
                    $myFile = 'demo.txt';
                    $titel = $_POST['filmnamn'] . ";" ;
                    $betyg = $_POST['betyg'] . ";" ;
                    $link = $_POST['link'] . ";" ;
                    $photo = $_POST['photo'] . ";" ;
                    $desc = $_POST['description'] . ";" ;
                    $data = "$titel$betyg$link$photo$desc";
                    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
                    fwrite($fh, $data);

                    fclose($fh);   
                 }
                }
          ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

To stop a form from submitting in the first place, you need HTML and Javascript. So basically, you link a function to the submit button, and it only submits if the function returns true.

```
<form action="..." method="post" onsubmit="return ValidatePage(this);">
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidatePage(form) { // the form itself is passed into the form variable. You can choose not to use it if you want.
       // validating stuff.
    }

</script>
```

Also, you'll need server side validation just in case someones being a jerk and turns of Javascript:

```
if ( !$title1) { echo "there has been an error" } // alternatively to the '!$title1' you can use empty($title1), which is what I use more often and may work better. Another possible alternative is to use a variable that you set to true if an error has occurred, that way the bulk of your code can be at the beginning.

else if... // repeat the if statement with else if for the remaining fields. 

else {...} // add the code to add to text file here.
```

There's a more complete example here: http://phpmaster.com/form-validation-with-php/ if you scroll down.

Also, you should know that there is no way in PHP to stop the form from submitting in the first place, all you can do is make it so that the form doesn't "do" anything.

Comment: client-side validation is for user comfort (no roundtrip to server), server-side validation is for data integrity. So better do it at least in PhP and eventually in Javascript.

Comment: @Bartdude, oops! I didn't read the full question. I thought he already had server side. I'll just add that.

Comment: ok, i hardly know any php and are trying to learn, i understand there is no way to stop it from submitting but as long as the form doesnt send anything my needs are met, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @spovell I think we have a misunderstanding. What do you mean by "submitting" vs. "sending". When a form submits, it means it sends the data. Those two words are synonyms.

Comment: ok, i mean when i push submit the form sends the data to the txt-file and if all the fields in the form are not filled in i dont want the form to send/submit the data to the txt-file!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !$title1 || !$betyg || !$link || !$photo || !$desc) {
//form + error message if blank
} else {
                        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
                        fwrite($fh, $data);
                        fclose($fh);       
}
```

The above will only validate all fields, not individual